# .any() is not recognising the truth value

Tags: python, list, boolean

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong here? I do not understand the error or how to fix it. Clearly start is in my list so why I am I not getting `True`?

```
local = [(0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 4), (0, 3)]
start = (0,5)
start == any(local)
```

Output ---> `False`

Comment: You mean `start in local`?

Comment: Yes I do I think. That seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`any` just checks whether at least one element in the iterable is truthy.
I think this is want you want:

```
local = [(0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 4), (0, 3)]
start = (0,5)
start in local
```

Answer (score 0):

any return a boolean while start is a tuple. Why comparing them should return True?

Answer (score 0):

one value is false, others are true
list = [0, 10, 5, 15]
print(any(list))

any just return the bool if there is any iterable